# Is it faster to port data from a C++ program to a Java program's input via sockets than via a raw json or xml file on the server?

Tags: java, c++, xml, json, sockets

What's the best way to go about things in terms of speed/performance?

Where do things like "Apache Thrift" come in and what are the benefits?

Please add some good resources I can use to learn about any recommendations!

Thanks all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presuming you mean both processes are already running, then it's going to be via sockets.

Writing a file to the disk from one process then reading it from the other is going to incur the performance hit of the disk write and read (and of course whatever method you employ to keep the reader from accessing the file until it's done being written; either locks or an atomic rename on the disk).

Even ignoring that, your localhost interface is going to have a faster transfer rate than your disk controller, with the possible exception of a 10Gb fiber channel RAID array with 15k RPM drives in it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it out. There's just no other way to find out.

Using sockets or the file system should be comparably fast, since both methods rely on some system calls that are very similar.

Always be aware that this communication involves these steps:

1. Encoding your data to a stream of bytes (JSON, XML, YAML, X.509 DER, Java Serialization)
2. Transferring this stream of bytes (TCP socket, UNIX socket, filesystem, ramdisk, pipes)
3. Decoding the stream of bytes into data (same as step 1)

Step 1 and 2 are completely independent, so take that into account when you benchmark.

Comment: Writing to a file on the filesystem is almost never going to be as fast as a socket connection.  Besides the consuming side would have to periodically poll the file to look for new input, which means you're already losing time.

Comment: There is no need to "find out" - transferring data on the localhost network interface is faster than your disk controller transfer rate (with the exception of a 10g fiberchannel RAID array with 15k RPM SAS drives, *maybe*. SATA2 still falls short). And that's ignoring the seek time and the fact that you need to sequentially access the file (writer then reader).

Comment: A filesystem doesn't have to have to do something with disks. As I wrote, it can also be an SSD or even a RAM disk. All I meant with filesystem was the interface through `open`, `read`, `write`, `close`.

Comment: Not to belabor the point, but let's pretend for a minute we're talking about a SSD even though that's going to be rare as a working drive on a server; nope ... still on a disk controller, and slower (SATA2 has a max throughput of 6Gb/sec which still falls short). In the absurd case that the server is using a RAM disk you might come close, except as you mention you're still dealing with a filesystem, which adds overhead that you don't have on a socket. What I mean is that these are all *known performance metrics* and your statement of "there's just no other way to find out" it patently false.